# How do I write on an Adobe Acrobat Reader document?

Tags: adobe-acrobat

Suppose I'm viewing some PDF, which contains math problems, in fullscreen mode. I'd like to create a textbox, or something similar, to write down my solutions. How would I go about doing so?

Comment: I believe Reader has a **commenting** feature.

Comment: @Scott Are you referring to **sticky notes**? I recall there being a different option but have trouble accessing it.

Comment: Well sticky notes *would* probably work but there are more features for **commenting** / **markup** / **annotations** -- https://helpx.adobe.com/acrobat/using/commenting-pdfs.html - Adobe Reader isn't designed to be a PDF *editor*.

Comment: @Scott Thank you, but it doesn't appear to explain how to use these features in fullscreen mode